# Handling data exceptions with JPA 2 persistence

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I'm using hibernate as JPA Persistence provider, and haven't been able to find any way to handle data exceptions in the documentation.

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="node_id")
    Node node;
    .. snip ..
}

@Entity
public class Node {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="node_id")
    List<Item> items;
    .. snip ..
}
```

In my database however, I have a data exception where there is an item row, with `node_id = X` but no node with `id` `X`.

I can't clean up this data for annoying, unrelated reasons.

Is there any way I can configure JPA to not explode when it hits this data?

Comment: This shows a lack of coherence in your database. There should be a foeign key constraint on this column, which would guarantee that this situation never happens. If cleaning up your data (which means executing a simple SQL query) is really not an option, then use Alex's answer. But you should clean it, and add a FK constraint.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are good reasons why in this case I can't clean this data up.  As I said, it's annoying.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the @NotFound(IGNORE) annotation on your property. Javadoc [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/NotFound.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't stifle JPA's exception. You can however create an entity listener that listens for entity save/update, and caches and deals with any exceptions that may come from them:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b28221/cmp30cfg015.htm

Comment: I'm not worried about persisting the object, I'm worried about loading it.